# Paypal Checkout window closes immediately in WKWebView(iOS)

Tags: html, ios, paypal, wkwebview, paypal-sandbox

I am using [Paypal Server Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/server-integration/) using an HTML page created at my end in iOS (Swift) and loading contents of this html file in WKWebView. It was wroking fine but suddenly the Paypal buttons starts working strangely as I click paypal button it opens checkout page and suddenly it closes the checkout popup automatically.

[CheckOutPage.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nuAgym5YhquXOBnAWmmN-tfcHoH4X6TK/view?usp=sharing)

[WKWebView.swift](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dr3pFHE9FIBlufFE784in9p0bmITrKsS/view?usp=sharing)

We are using same checkout html code for website and it is working fine there. But the checkout is not working in iOS app.

Need help with this .....

[image: HTML Page loaded]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Do not use a webview](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications), only a Safari View Controller that shows an address bar is supported.

Comment: Thanks for the lead but I am loading an HTML page ([CheckOut.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nuAgym5YhquXOBnAWmmN-tfcHoH4X6TK/view)  that is saved at my end in iOS Project)  into WKWebView and that's not possible using SFSafariViewController as it takes only HTTP and HTTPS URLs not some URLs from my Bundle ... 
Any leads, how can I implement Paypal using SFSafariViewController in the iOS app ?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. The page invoking the PayPal Checkout JS needs to be HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: If you wish to integrate natively (not web), use Native Checkout for iOS, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/